# how to create soap xml request in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, api, soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SubmitRequest xmlns="http://tripauthority.com/hotel">
      <siteID>string</siteID>
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <xmlFormattedString>string</xmlFormattedString>
    </SubmitRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

we have to call above soap xml. i have siteID, username, password.
where string is below

```
<ArnRequest><Availability DisplayCurrency="USD" SearchTimeout="15"><HotelAvailability InDate="2007-04-26" OutDate="2007-04-29" Rooms="1" Adults="2" Children="0"><Hotel HotelID="8800"/></HotelAvailability></Availability></ArnRequest>
```

i have no idea on soap request. Please help with this to get response on above soap xml in PHP. The above xml is of ARN(Alliance reservations)
thanks in advance.

Comment: The [***TripAuthority Web Services API***](http://www.alliancereservations.com/xml-web-services.html) is very clear about problems like yours: *" XML integration is for serious businesses only; it will require major development and is not suitable for a part time developer or first time developer attempting to learn on the job."* and they continue: *"We charge a $5000 integration fee before you're allowed access to the API to begin development."* - If you just want to do a Soap Request with PHP I suggest you just orient with many of the duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solve my question if any body in future have any problem they this code works for him, please check-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('API_SITEID',    $your_siteid);
define('API_USERNAME',  $your_uname);
define('API_PASSWORD',  $your_pass);
define('API_WSDL',      'http://tripauthority.com/hotel.asmx?WSDL');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$xmlReq = '<ArnRequest>
<Availability DisplayCurrency="USD" SearchTimeout="15">
    <HotelAvailability InDate="2014-09-26" OutDate="2014-09-27" Rooms="1" Adults="1" Children="0">
    <Hotel HotelID="8800"/>
    </HotelAvailability>
</Availability>
</ArnRequest>';
echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <strong>XML Request:</strong>
    <p>
    <textarea style="width:100%;height:400px;" id="xmlReq" name="xmlReq">'.$xmlReq.'</textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Test Request">
    <input type="hidden" name="avail" id="avail" value="y">
</form>';

if($_POST['avail'] == "y") {
    $xmlRes = doSoapRequest((($_POST['xmlReq']) ? $_POST['xmlReq'] : $xmlReq));
    echo '<strong>XML Response:</strong>
    <p>
    <textarea style="width:100%;height:400px;" id="xmlRes" name="xmlRes">'.$xmlRes.'</textarea>
    </p>';
}

function doSoapRequest($xmlReq) {
        try {
    $client = new SoapClient(API_WSDL);
    return $client->SubmitRequestRpc(API_SITEID, API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD, $xmlReq);
    } catch(SoapFault $exception) {
    return "Fault Code: {$exception->getMessage()}";
    }
}
```

?>

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Calling webservices is quite easy, if you just want to send a prepared raw xml request. You could for instance use CURL for this.

Here the code which uses the php soapclient. I get "invalid credentials", but this should be ok as you'd put your valid ones in there.

```
<?

$string ='<ArnRequest><Availability DisplayCurrency="USD" SearchTimeout="15"><HotelAvailability InDate="2007-04-26" OutDate="2007-04-29" Rooms="1" Adults="2" Children="0"><Hotel HotelID="8800"/></HotelAvailability></Availability></ArnRequest>';

$xmlrequest = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hot="http://tripauthority.com/hotel">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hot:SubmitRequestDoc>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <hot:siteID>string</hot:siteID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <hot:aUserName>string</hot:aUserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <hot:aPassword>string</hot:aPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <hot:aRequestDoc>
'.$string.'
</hot:aRequestDoc>
      </hot:SubmitRequestDoc>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


//Change this variables.
$location_URL = 'http://tripauthority.com/hotel.asmx';
$action_URL = "http://tripauthority.com/hotel/SubmitRequestDoc";

$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => $location_URL,
'uri'      => "http://tripauthority.com/hotel",
'trace'    => 1,
));

$order_return = $client->__doRequest($xmlrequest,$location_URL,$action_URL,1);

//Get response from here
print_r($order_return);

?>
```

Comment: hi aydinK thanks for your answer but when i am running above code with right credentials i am getting `null is not allowed as a predicate value, use Sql.IsNull instead for field UserName ` as response, not able to find out problem where is it. Here i am not seeing header included
`POST /hotel.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: tripauthority.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length` is this also we have to mention in our code. please help

Answer (score 1):

php has a built in Soap Client as of 5: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

```
$wsdl = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SubmitRequest xmlns="http://tripauthority.com/hotel">
      <siteID>string</siteID>
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <xmlFormattedString>string</xmlFormattedString>
    </SubmitRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
';

try {

     $client = @new SOAPClient($wsdl);  // or preferably, use a url for $wsdl

    // Be sure to replace soapMethodToUse with a mouthed for this specific web service.
    $response = $client->soapMethodToUse(array('key' => 'val')); // Any params for this method

} catch (Exception $e) {  

    echo $e->getMessage(); 

}

die(var_dump($response));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply c-griffin.
i tried your code and get something error.
`SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ' siteid uname pass ' : failed to load external entity "`
can you help me with this to resolve and run with some response
where siteid , uname, pass is unique parameter which i have

Comment: Try putting the xml in a file, then passing the file path when instantiating the SoapClient. new SOAPClient('file.wsdl');  Or, a lot of Web Service providers will give you a url to your WSDL, you can pass that URL as well.

Comment: also try as your suggestion but not able to get fruitfull result do we have to mention `POST /hotel.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: tripauthority.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length` above header in our code as i am not finding this code in our page.. please help

Answer (score 0):

You may try to modify request with help of __doRequest function.

```
<?php
require_once("MySoapClient.php");
$client = new MySoapClient($wsdUrl,array(
                                       'location' => "http://tripauthority.com/hotel",
                                       'trace'    => 1,
                                       'cache_wsdl' =>  WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                                       )
                         );
$parameters=array('siteID'=>'string','username'=>'string','password'=>'string');
$err=0;
try{
    $info = $client->__soapCall("SubmitRequest",array($parameters));
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "<pre>faultcode: '".$e->faultcode."'</pre>";
    echo "<pre>faultstring: '".$e->getMessage()."'</pre>";
    $err=1;
}
if($err==0)
    print_r($info);
else
    echo $client->__getLastRequest();
?>
```

MySoapClient.php

```
<?php
class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        $request=str_replace('</SubmitRequest>','<xmlFormattedString>string</xmlFormattedString></SubmitRequest>',$request);
        return $request;
    }
}
?>
```